# Crystal report not working Azure web apps

Tags: azure, crystal-reports, azure-web-app-service

We are using crystal reports in asp.net application (https://kegxchange.azurewebsites.net/)
However when we publish the application we are getting the error “Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.Web”.  Is it possible to install crystal reports runtime for this site or is there any work around solution for running crystal reports. We are running this application successfully in the production hosted server for the past few years without any issues. Since we are moving this app to azure platform, it would be good if we run the same application without any changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run Crystal Reports in Azure Web Apps as you can't install COM components in the Web Apps sandbox.  You need to use a Virtual Machine to do so and your app should run without any changes.

BTW, on feedback.azure.com, the request to add Crystal Reports support to Web Apps was declined ([link](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6771442-crystal-reports-in-azure-websites)).

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to install crystal reports runtime for this site

Unfortunately, Crystal Reports is **not supported** in Azure Web Apps. As the WebApp is a [sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox).

> Is there any work around solution for running crystal reports.

You could use Azure VM or cloud service to do that.  You could learn more info from [Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm).

**Reference:**

[How to: Migrate and Publish a Web Application to an Azure Cloud Service from Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service)