# Deploy Azure application ASP.NET with C# - Error CrystalReports

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

I come to ask for guidance to this great Microsoft .NET community

I am a Java dev and I have always worked with architectures designed for Java environments.

I ended up having the opportunity to implement an ASP project. NET with C # in a clound environment at AZURE.

A great learning experience for those who have never worked or studied tools and languages ​​of the .NET ecosystem.

If anyone knows how to guide me, I would be very grateful, I already did the study on the Internet about the problem and I didn't find a simple solution, or at least not for me.

My problem is as follows: After deploying the project to Azure via the Visual Studio 2012 tool's public menu, we had the message when trying to access the application through the browser:

[image]

The project uses tools called Crystal and another called Telerik for reports and graphs.

In order to set up the local development environment, we had to install these tools, but how to install them there in the Azure environment? There is my problem, I still couldn't find a solution to do this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you expand on "deploying the project to Azure". I guessed you deployed to an Azure App Service (not an Azure VM)? I have found that a publish from VS usually grabs all dependencies.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Exactly don't create vm on Azure, create one
Application Service

Comment: @EdeGerSil It is Crystal Report error. Make sure that they have setup CR for you on the server. If they don't support it, your CR won't work. I would recommend you to check Asphostportal if you want to run CR.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Unfortunately they have nothing set up, crystal or telerik, I am doing everything and stopped this problem. Some people suggesting including crystal .exe and .msi files in the project and creating a bash file to run with the project, I don't know if this is possible or feasible.
Ex: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not load file or assembly after publishing to Azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50615813/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-after-publishing-to-azure-app-service)

Comment: Actually, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47991213/crystal-report-not-working-azure-web-apps) that states "Crystal Reports are not supported in Azure Web Apps"

Answer (score 1):

App Service Web Apps runs in a secure environment called a sandbox ofr security reasons but has some limits.

For more information:

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox

One possibility is to use a Windows Container. Here you can follow the quickstart to run a Windows Container in App Service:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-windows-container

In this case Hyper-V is used as the sandbox to run the Windows Container.

Comment: Hello @Joaquin Vano, in that case I would see to delete all environment that I created and create a container or a virtual machine?

Comment: Yes the easiest solution is probably to just create a VM in Azure and install your libraries on there and install the web app normally.

Comment: There are people indicating this solution http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2012/01/crystal-reports-on-azure-how-to.html too, I don't know if it is possible. But giving everything wrong I will create the vms. Thanks for the answer

Comment: First create a Windows Container with 2019 lts tag
Then upload the container to Azure Container Registry
Then follow the quick start to host the container in App Service and enjoy of all the App Service additional features that you wont have in a regular VM